# OpenCV: Compute a single HOG vector for the whole image and get block locations

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I work with **OpenCV 2.4** in **C++**.

I have some image, say, 360x240 (but it is not relevant), and I want to compute one HOG vector for the whole image.

- Is there any short way to do it, or should I initialize an object of `gpu::HOGDescriptor` with `winSize` equals to the image size?
- Is the `winSize` parameter anyway relevant when you use the `getDescriptors()` method (or is it relevant only for the detection related methods)?
- Is there some easy way to tell the coordinates in the image of each block in the vector?

Answer (score 3):

- Set the winSize is the correct way.
- This parameter is relevant for the `getDescriptors()` because it defines the size of your descriptor. The descriptor of size `winSize` is first devided into cell of size `cellSize`. For each cell a histogram of oriented gradients is build. The descriptor is further arranged in Blocks. A Block uses `blockSize.width * blockSize.height` adjecent cells in order to estimate a normalize the histogram out of the `blockSize.width * blockSize.height` cell histomgrams. `blockStride` can be use to arange the blocks in an overlapping manner. Finaly all normalized histograms estimated for each Block are concatenated which defines the final descriptor vector length. [here](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/2011/results/proj4/hangsu/) you can find a good visualisation. So different sizes can result in various descriptor length.
- If you mean the locations of the HoG descriptors you can use the `locations` attribute of the `compute` function.